# Hide biography post facebook sdk

Tags: facebook, post, sdk, hide

How I can hide my post from APP, ie only visualize in WALL but not in the biography. bi some pages that published in my name but did not appear in my biography, is there any way

Use this code to post, but found the way to hide in the biography

```
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {message: 'Hello, world!',link: 'https://www.facebook.com' });
```

}, {scope: 'publish_actions'});